# Select 2nd to last date with Group By

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following query which I hoped would grab the data with the second to latest date

```
SELECT mn.meter_name, m.meter_number, m.meter_location, r.rates_meter_rate,
       r.rates_meter_PPD, m.meter_ID, mt.metertracking_readend,                        
       mt.metertracking_conversion, mt.metertracking_periodend 
FROM db_meters m, db_meters_name mn, db_rates_meter r, db_meters_tracking mt 
WHERE m.ICP_ID = '227' AND m.meter_name_ID = mn.meter_name_ID 
   AND r.meter_ID = m.meter_ID AND r.contract_ID = '70' AND mt.meter_ID = m.meter_ID   
   AND metertracking_periodend = ( 
      SELECT max(metertracking_periodend) 
      FROM db_meters_tracking 
      WHERE meter_ID = mt.meter_ID 
      AND metertracking_periodend < (SELECT MAX(metertracking_periodend) 
          FROM db_meters_tracking) 
     GROUP BY meter_ID ) 
ORDER BY  metertracking_periodend
```

This outputs the following:

```
meter_name  meter_number  meter_location   rates_meter_rate  rates_meter_PPD  meter_ID  metertracking_readend  metertracking_conversion  metertracking_periodend

Anytime     9011656:1     in front office  0.13870           10.000           15        73856                  0.0000                     2013-11-29
Anytime     9011656:2     in front office  0.13870           10.000           16        2899                   1.0000                     2013-11-29
```

However I am expecting the following:

```
meter_name  meter_number  meter_location   rates_meter_rate  rates_meter_PPD  meter_ID  metertracking_readend  metertracking_conversion  metertracking_periodend

Anytime     9011656:1     in front office  0.13870           10.000           15        0                      0.0000                     2013-10-31
Anytime     9011656:2     in front office  0.13870           10.000           16        0                      1.0000                     2013-10-31
```

I have attached a screenshot of the table as well [image]

Any ideas where I am going wrong? or what the SQL query would actually be to accomplish this? Many Thanks.

Comment: If you insist on using your query then add `WHERE meter_ID = mt.meter_ID` to the innermost query here: AND metertracking_periodend < (SELECT MAX(metertracking_periodend) FROM db_meters_tracking WHERE meter_ID = mt.meter_ID). However, this query is a perfect example for ROW_NUMBER() OVER clause. Read about it, it is very easy to use

Comment: @cha that worked, thank you very much. If you want to add it as an answer I will mark it.
I'm certainly open to a more efficient query

Comment: Just wanted to add to my previous comment, that ROW_NUMBER is not supported in MySQL. For some reasons I assumed that it was ORACLE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rewrote the query like this (I have not tested it, but I think it is correct):

```
SELECT mn.meter_name, m.meter_number, m.meter_location, r.rates_meter_rate,
       r.rates_meter_PPD, m.meter_ID, mt.metertracking_readend,                        
       mt.metertracking_conversion, mt.metertracking_periodend 
FROM db_meters m INNER JOIN db_meters_name mn ON m.meter_name_ID = mn.meter_name_ID
     INNER JOIN db_rates_meter r ON r.meter_ID = m.meter_ID 
     INNER JOIN db_meters_tracking mt ON mt.meter_ID = m.meter_ID
WHERE m.ICP_ID = '227' AND r.contract_ID = '70' 
AND 2 = (SELECT count(DISTINCT a.metertracking_periodend)
     FROM db_meters_tracking a 
     WHERE a.meter_ID = r.meter_ID AND mt.metertracking_periodend <= a.metertracking_periodend)
ORDER BY m.meter_ID, metertracking_periodend
```

See [this post](http://www.abhishekbpatel.com/2012/12/how-to-get-nth-maximum-and-minimun.html) for reference.

On a side note, please use INNER JOINs instead of comma separated tables in the FROM clause. It is now considered a standard

Comment: Not quite. It grabs the correct date for the 2nd meter (16) but not the first (15) it returns '2013-07-31' which is the earliest date